Data provider hooks in new react-admin version with nullable record context
In React-Admin the useRecordContext is now nullable. Before I could have a component that gets me the record and then fetches (or does something else with the data provider) something related to the record like this:
export const ExampleComponent= () => {
  const record = useRecordContext<User>();

  const { data } = useGetOne<Car>(`user/${record.userId}/cars/${record.carId}`, {});

  return <>{data.name}<>
}

However, since now the record can be undefined I can't do this anymore. According to the migration docs I should just check if record is undefined and return in such cases, however, this is not possible because of the rules of hooks. useGetOne can't be called conditionally:

React Hook "useGetOne" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be
called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you
accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?

How should such situations be handled? Handing over the record through props and only render the component when record is defined?

The useGetOne hook also consumes options, which are passed to the underlying useQuery hook. You can set the enabled option based on the availability of a defined record value. See Dependent Queries for complete details.
Example Implementation:
const record = useRecordContext<User>();

const { data } = useGetOne<Car>(
  // Resource
  `user/${record.userId}/cars/${record.carId}`,
  // Meta
  {},
  // Options
  {
    enabled: !!record // <-- only enable when record is truthy
  }
);


So in such a case you would do a null-check override of the record!.userId, right?

@Heikkisorsa Are you asking about the "resource" URL path part? If so, then yeah, you may need an appropriate null-check if it's constructed each render cycle regardless of the query's status. I would suggest Optional Chaining over the non-null assertion, e.g. user/${record?.userId}/cars/${record?.carId}. Does this make sense?

yes, exactly. It's just a bit weird to use optional chaining here, as it could lead to misformed API calls without proper IDs.

@Heikkisorsa I can understand the concern, but I think it's fine. The userId and carId properties will only be accessed if record is defined, and these properties should exist since you are using Typescript, and the query should only be executed when record is defined. It would seem very unlikely, or even impossible (even though I hate absolutes in engineering), that a malformed URL path string could be computed for the request. This all OFC assumes that record.userId and record.carId are also valid types/values, but TS should help with that.

@Heikkisorsa If you wanted, you could strengthen the condition to enabled: record?.userId && record?.carId, or more, to ensure the computed request path is a accurate as possible.
